# SimpleModal IE8 Issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, simplemodal

Having issues in Internet Explorer... Of Course.
Every other browser I have tested in it works great...
I was hoping someone could help me out
Basically if referrer wasn't us display simplemodal popup.

```
 <!-- Init Age Verification Content -->

<div class="age" id="verify"> 
    <div><img src="/image/white.png"></img></div>
    <div id="noman">ARE YOU OVER 18?</div>
    <div> 
      <p> If not, leave now and we wont tell your mom.
        </br>  By continuing you agree you are 18 or older.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="YN">
      <a href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href" id="old">Yes</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="http://www.sendoff.com" rel="nofollow" id="young">No</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- If previous page wasnt from us... Verify -->

  <script>
if ( document.referrer == null || document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.hostname) < 0 ) {
$("#verify").modal({opacity:85, position: ["20%",""], onOpen: function (dialog) {
    dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
        dialog.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
            dialog.data.fadeIn('slow');
            return false;
        });
    });
}});
}
</script>
```

But I keep getting this error in IE8:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)
Timestamp: Tue, 16 Jul 2013 12:14:28 UTC


Message: Not implemented

Line: 454
Char: 7
Code: 0
URI: http://www.example.com/catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.4.js


Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: http://www.example.com/
```

Thank you for your help in Advance guys!

Comment: Have you seen [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/simplemodal/issues/detail?id=7)? Tried changing `ieQuirks = $.browser.msie && !$.boxModel;` to `ieQuirks = jQuery.support.boxModel;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try running your script only after the DOM has loaded

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if ( document.referrer == null || document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.hostname) < 0 ) {
$("#verify").modal({opacity:85, position: ["20%",""], onOpen: function (dialog) {
    dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
        dialog.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
            dialog.data.fadeIn('slow');
            return false;
        });
    });
}});
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: This worked but now when you click the yes link it just keeps bringing up the simplemodal over and over.

Comment: With the help of some others I got this working correctly. Please see [This workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012180/simple-modal-wont-close-ie8-bug-window-location-href) for the final solution.