# Simple Modal Wont Close | IE8 Bug | window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, simplemodal

I posted earlier about 1 issue I was having. Got that fixed but it brought up another issue...

The code below...

When clicking "Yes" In every other browser The page will reload without SimpleModal coming back up.

But in IE8 it continuously loads SimplModal thereby denying access to the site...

Thanks for your help in advance guys!

```
 <!-- Init Age Verification Content -->

<div class="age" id="verify"> 
    <div><img src="white.png"></img></div>
    <div id="noman">ARE YOU OVER 18?</div>
    <div> 
      <p> If not, leave now and we wont tell your mom.
        </br>  By continuing you agree you're 18 or older.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="YN">
      <a href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href" id="old">Yes</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="example.com" rel="nofollow" id="young">No</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- If previous page wasn't from us... Verify -->

  <script>
if ( document.referrer == null || document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.hostname) < 0 ) {
$("#verify").modal({opacity:85, position: ["20%",""], onOpen: function (dialog) {
    dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
        dialog.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
            dialog.data.fadeIn('slow');
            return false;
        });
    });
}});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Start by verifying which is unexpected: `document.referrer` *or* `window.location.hostname`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply :) Could you be a little more specific? Im by no means a coder. Thank you!

Comment: Open up IE Developer Tools (press F12) in IE8 (or a higher version of IE and choose IE8/8 as the model). Then, on the page that displays the modal dialog when it ought not to, type in both `document.referrer` (and `window.location.href`) on the Console and observe the values. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(v=vs.85).aspx (for IE8) or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx (for "F12"). I suspect that `document.referrer` is the "incorrect" value in this case.

Comment: The `document.referrer` feature is unreliable and you really just shouldn't use it at all.

Comment: I don't know of any other way to have it so that on any page a person comes through if it is there first time on the website do an age verification and if they click ok send them to the page they requested. I can't change the link to a url because they could be coming from different pages. I am going to try the answer below as soon as I figure out how to implement it lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE doesn't set a document.referrer if the user didn't navegate to the page through a link

> From the MDN documentation: "*The value is an empty string if the user
>   navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example,
>   via a bookmark). Since this property returns only a string, it does
>   not give you DOM access to the referring page.*"

Simply change the link's href to your page's address or try this workaround.

```
<a href="javascript:redirect(window.location.href);" id="old">Yes</a>

<script type="text/javascript" >            
function redirect(url) {
    if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        var referLink = document.createElement('a');
        referLink.href = url;
        document.body.appendChild(referLink);
        referLink.click();
    } else {
        location.href = url;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how this worked but it worked. :) I added this script right after my current script and all problems were solved. Thanks man!